# Any GameObject.Find alternatives in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I cannot find anything after perusing the documentation (who knows I might've missed it), but I am trying to get access to a node in an existing scene and use it to set the position of the node getting it.

Perusing the documentation, finding a gameobject.find alternative, i did not find it.

Comment: The real question is: Do you have a specific nodes in mind? How are they positioned in your tree? Do you plan to use this feature more than once, or is it for let's say a spawner? The answers you already got might work, but without a tree (and because I guess you are new) a simple get_node call might do the trick for you..

Answer (score 0):

I use a Global.cs with:

```
static Node Root;
public static void SetRoot(Node node) => Root = node;
public static T FindChild<T>(Node node = null)
{
    if (node is T t) return t;

    Godot.Collections.Array<Node> children = node is null ? Root.GetChildren() : node.GetChildren();
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        T c = FindChild<T>(child);
        if (c is not null) return c;
    }
    
    return default;
}
```

For the node I want to find, I attach a unique script to the node (in the example below: NameLineEdit.cs)

Then in the first node that runs, set the root, then you can do find-by-type:

```
public override void _Ready()
{
    Global.SetRoot(GetNode("/root"));

    _nameLineEdit = Global.FindChild<NameLineEdit>();
}
```

The catch being that the first `_Ready()` will be a lowest child.

It's not ideal and I'd be interested in improvements that simplify this setup.

If you need a FindAll to grab a List, that should be fairly easy to add. I haven't done it because I only use this at app initialization to wire everything together.

Comment: quick question (might be dumb), but this looks like C# to me... I was asking for answer in GDScript, so if you have any expertise in that if you could translate, that would be very cool

Answer (score 0):

You can add that one object to a group and then use

```
for gameObject in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("group_name"):
    // do stuff with gameObject
```

[documentation link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjGmbCWpNqCAxXnSPEDHRVQAKYQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.godotengine.org%2Fen%2Fstable%2Ftutorials%2Fscripting%2Fgroups.html&usg=AOvVaw0l6eSq3w3Lj6OaEkrXnfpk&opi=89978449)

Comment: Is there any way you can explain this code? It worked, but I want to really understand the reasoning behind why adding "for gameObject in" suddenly makes everything work. Thanks!

Comment: gameObject is just the variable name. this starts a for loop, which goes through all the nodes in the group "group_name". every object you added to that group will be handled in that for loop. if youre unfamiliar with for loops (https://gdscript.com/tutorials/looping/)